# What are the most interesting projects surrounding python?

Tags: python, project

There are many neat projects around that are extending the usefulness of python inside and outside the core language and standard library.  Some that come to mind are:

- [pypy](https://web.archive.org/web/20120108201816/http://codespeak.net/pypy/dist/pypy/doc/)
- [stackless](https://github.com/stackless-dev/stackless/wiki/)
- [twisted](https://web.archive.org/web/20220702232042/https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/)
- [unladen swallow](https://web.archive.org/web/20160411184153/https://code.google.com/p/unladen-swallow/)
- [web](https://www.djangoproject.com/) [frameworks](https://www.turbogears.org/)
- [numpy](https://numpy.org/)
- [function annotations](https://peps.python.org/pep-3107/)
- [other interesting ideas](https://web.archive.org/web/20220308192429/https://www.python.org/dev/peps/)

What are some of the projects that get you excited, on and off this list?

Comment: Should be Community Wiki

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is that?

Comment: Basically they are for posts where you're asking for *opinions* rather than *answers*. Click edit question and check "community wiki" to turn this into one.

Comment: Probably should be tagged subjective as well.

Answer (score 4):

My favorites:

- Full-featured web frameworks like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) - making basic web development really easy.
- [PyQt](https://riverbankcomputing.com/news) - binding the full power of the Qt framework to Python
- [Pygame](https://www.pygame.org/news.html) - [easy and fun](https://web.archive.org/web/20140728032407/http://eli.thegreenplace.net/category/programming/python/pygame-tutorial/) game development
- [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) - publication-quality scientific plots for any purpose

Answer (score 1):

[Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/): "Sage is a free open-source  mathematics software system licensed under the GPL. It combines the power of many existing open-source packages into a common Python-based interface."

Answer (score 1):

[Pyjamas](http://pyjs.org) (PyJS) - Unified web and GUI framework with all components being done in native python (no more annoying JS).

Answer (score 0):

[Reportlab](https://web.archive.org/web/20140330134217/http://www.reportlab.com/software/opensource/) - Programatic creation of PDFs.

I second all of Eli's suggestions, all realy excellent stuff especially PyQt and [PySide](https://wiki.qt.io/PySide2).

Answer (score 0):

i like [zope](http://zope.org) and [plone](http://plone.org) very much.

Answer (score 0):

[PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/) - Python Lex-Yacc

It (ab)uses Python's docstrings to allow you to embed BNF grammar files directly into the code.